# Increase the performance of this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2019

I am running the below query, and it has a performance issue.

```
SELECT TOP 5000 
    mseg.werks
FROM
    mkpf
INNER JOIN 
    mseg ON mkpf.mandt = mseg.mandt
         AND mkpf.mblnr = mseg.mblnr
GROUP BY 
    mseg.werks
```

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkYQfQcya)

**Indexes**

- `MKPF` - clustered index on columns `mandt, mblnr, abc` in that order
- `MSEG` - non-clustered index on the column `werks`
- `MSEG` - clustered index on columns `mandt, mblnr, abc, xyz` in that order

Row counts:

- `MKPF` - 50 million rows
- `MSEG` - 150 million rows

Initially, it was just the two clustered indexes, and the query was very slow. So, I created the non clustered index on the column `werks`. But, it's still taking a little over two minutes to produce results. I would like to get it under 30 seconds or at least a minute.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**Edit**

Adding a bit more context: The above query is part of a larger query. But, the larger query in this case is essentially doing what I have posted. The rest of it comes into play in other use cases where other columns need to be pulled from the tables `MSEG` and `MKPF` depending on what the user wants to see. Due to this, there are limitations to how much the query can be rewritten as all the columns need to be accessible from `MSEG` and `MKPF`. Not sharing the whole query as it is part of an IP.

Comment: Try adding a non-clustered index on the MSEC table with mandt, mblnr, weeks as key columns.  If the index key values are unique, declare indexes as unique as well. Speed depends on your infrastructure so I can't say if 30 seconds is reasonable.

Comment: @DanGuzman Wouldn't adding columns (mandt & mblnr) that are part of the clustered index to a non-clustered index be redundant? since sql server already does that for every non-clustered index.

Comment: The clustered index key columns are effectively included columns rather than key columns in the non-clustered index. They can help cover they query but cannot be used to facilitate for ordered operations (e.g. merge join, stream aggregate) unless they are key columns.

Comment: if you use TOP, perhaps doing WHERE EXISTS instead of join might be more performant?

Comment: The [plan](https://checktheplan.com/?p=d5c1b1f28afb419aac5afd64dc1eea3a&l=st) says you are reading 155 million rows. That's bound to be slow.

Comment: Why are you grouping, when you are not aggregating? Using `DISTINCT` makes it more intuitive what the query is suppposed to do (though won't help performance). If you use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`, you get 'some' 5000 rows. There is no guarantee you'll get the same 5000 rows next time you execute it. `TOP` should **always** have an `ORDER BY`. This might have a performance impact. Finally, you may get better performance if you allow parallelism.

Comment: @DanGuzman Okay, thank you for clarifying that. I tried with the index you suggested, but SQL Server is choosing the previous one. So, I tried forcing it, but it didn't make a difference to the performance.

Comment: I see from your comment to @Charlieface's answer the query in the question isn't the whole story. The actual DDL and query will help us help you better.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added a bit more context in my reply to `@Charlieface` and in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, given the low cardinality of distinct `mseg.werks` values (estimated 2141 in this case), the best option is probably to create an indexed view.

```sql
CREATE VIEW vw_Werks
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
    mseg.werks,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS TotalCount
FROM
    dbo.mkpf
INNER JOIN
    dbo.mseg ON mkpf.mandt = mseg.mandt
            AND mkpf.mblnr = mseg.mblnr
GROUP BY 
    mseg.werks;
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON vw_Werks (werks);
```

Now query it like this, note the use of `NOEXPAND`

```
SELECT TOP (5000)
    mseg.werks
FROM
    vw_Werks mseg WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

The server will automatically maintain the indexed view, and it effectively functions as a pre-joined index.

Comment: This works like a charm, the results are instantaneous. Unfortunately, the query I posted is part of a larger query and integrating the suggested solution is not possible. The program, depending on the user action will modify the larger base query to fetch the needed columns. But, this solution can certainly help others that don't have my limitation.

Comment: Well query performance issues cannot really be diagnosed by only posting part of a query. I suggest you create a *new* question showing your actual query, along with all relevant tables and index definitions (full DDL please) and the PasteThePlan link.

Comment: The larger query in this case is essentially doing what I have posted. The rest of it only comes into play in other use cases where other columns need to be pulled from the tables 'mseg' and 'mkpf'. I was hoping there would be some indexing solution that I was missing, but it looks like re-writing the query like you showed is the only way to make it faster. Also, I didn't post the whole code as it is an IP, and cannot be shared, sorry. But, thank you for your input, learned something new.